# Open Source Alternative to Rave.DJ?

Tags: open-source, music, artificial-intelligence

[rave.dj](https://rave.dj) is a site that allows you to create mash-ups or mixes of multiple songs automatically. They are closed-source and it can only be operated through their website.

Are there any existing open-source alternatives to this? I have a project I'd like to implement it into, but if one doesn't exist I'll develop my own one (I have a pretty good idea as to how it operates).

It doesn't have to do additional functions, such as also creating a mash-up for each song's corresponding music video, but it should be able the create coherent mash-ups of at least 2 songs.

**Edit:** Any license is fine for me, my project is personal and non-commercial.

Comment: Please see my answer and check, is this library is meet your requirements or not?

Comment: Please see my answer and check, is this library is meet your requirements nor not?

Answer (score 1):

ITNOA

I think [Mixxx](https://github.com/mixxxdj/mixxx) can useful for you

In description of this library you can see `Mixxx is Free DJ software that gives you everything you need to perform live DJ mixes. Mixxx works on GNU/Linux, Windows, and macOS.`

The [site](https://mixxx.org/) is useful information about this.